# google spreadsheet: join arrays using function NOT CODE

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have one array

```
1 
2
3
```

another array

```
4
5
6
```

How do I use one function to join the 2 arrays?

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Let's say your arrays are:

A1:A3 = `{1;2;3}` and B1:B3 = `{4;5;6}`

Write somewhere: `={A1:A3;B1:B3}`

Semicolons `;` are used to separate rows, and commas `,` are for columns.

Here is the documentation: [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)

Answer (score 10):

```
TRANSPOSE() //takes matrix as argument and returns transposed matrix
SPLIT() //breaks apart a string based on a delimiter character (char(13) here)
ARRAYFORMULA() //applies the formula within to array vs cell
CONCATENATE() //joins each cell in each range with a char(13), then the next cell...then the next matrix of cells (to which the first process also happens)
//note char(13) is a carriage return, i will call CR for ease
```

so if you have matrix A : 1, 2, 3
and matrix B : 4, 5, 6

the steps would look like this:

```
TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE("1CR2CR3CR" ; "4CR5CR6CR")), CR))
TRANSPOSE(SPLIT("1CR2CR3CR4CR5CR6CR", "CR"))
TRANSPOSE({"1","2","3","4","5","6"})
```

finally:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: i saw that but couldn't understand how to translate it to my situation. could you translate it for me please?

Comment: @Mr.Monshaw, Why is arrayformula needed in the first `transpose`?

Answer (score 10):

=FLATTEN(A1:A3,B1:B3) should do the trick

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

```
=filter({A1:A;B1:B}, {A1:A;B1:B}<>"")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! A code-only answer isn't very useful for other users searching for a solution. Could you add an explanation to what your code does?

Answer (score 2):

I'm noticing this is an older question, so this might not have existed when previous responses were written.

You're looking for the **JOIN()** formula.

([Documentation link](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en&authuser=0))

**Sample Usage**

```
JOIN(" and-a ",{1,2,"1 2 3 4"})

JOIN(",",{1,2,3},{4;5;6})

JOIN("-",A1:A100)
```

**Syntax**

```
JOIN(delimiter, value_or_array1, [value_or_array2, ...])
```

delimiter - The character or string to place between each concatenated value.

delimiter may be specified as blank, e.g. JOIN(,{1,2,3}).
value_or_array1 - The value or values to be appended using delimiter.

value_or_array2, ... - [ OPTIONAL ] - Additional value or array to be appended using delimiter.

Comment: Doesn't `join` compacts everything into one cell?

Answer (score 1):

Given the information provided by Mr.Monshaw, I figured this out for you.

Given values "1,2,3" are in cells A1:A3 of a spreadsheet, and values "4,5,6,7" are in cells B1:B4.  Here is the formula to use:

=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE(concat(A1:A3,",");concat(B1:B4,","))),","))

Explanation.
The concat formula creates a string of the values with the indicated separator, ",". So concat(A1:A3,",") results in "1,2,3".

The Concatenate combines the values of the specified array as one string. So CONCATENATE(concat(A1:A3,",");concat(B1:B4,",")) results in "1,2,3,4,5,6,7"

The Split function here is used to identify the "," as a deliminator and not a value in the array.  The Transpose will cause the results to display in a column instead of in a row.

Answer (score 1):

I found this even easier...

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({A:A;B:B})
```