# ImportRange "Result to large" - How to import all the data I need?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I have a spreadsheet with 140.000 rows and 5 columns. I need to import all of that to another spreadsheet to apply a query and filter some information.

I can only import 20.000 rows with ImportRange because otherwise, I have a "Result too large" error. Doesn't matter if it is inside a QUERY formula.

¿How can I import or do a Query on all the 140.000 rows?

I haven't tried anything else cause I don't know any more tricks to make it happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for a formula based solution, then use as many IMPORTRANGE as necessary to import all the required rows inside an array. The formula will look something similar to the following (assuming that A1 has the spreadsheet key )

```
={
IMPORTRANGE(A1,"A1:E20000");
IMPORTRANGE(A1,"A20001:E40000");
IMPORTRANGE(A1,"A40001:E60000");
...
}
```

Reference

- [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)

Related

- [Appending google spreadsheet arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15985637/1595451)
- [google spreadsheet: join arrays using function NOT CODE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17885374/1595451)